# SpagoBI _ Exporting Documents

Tags: spagobi

Does anyone know how to export a document\set of documents (cockpits, reports, charts, etc) from one server instance to another?

I haven't found any info on this subject and really would like to know, as it's important for future development and upgrading. We want\need to have two separated environments, one for dev and another for use by end-client.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

See my write-up of Exporting SpagoBI Report Documents from one server and importing them into another SpagoBI Server.  That will will give you a largely manual process, but it is repeatable. 
[Exporting and Importing of SpagoBI Documents](https://www.davidbharrison.com/spagobi-exporting-and-importing-report-documents/)

If you're interested in exporting one report document, possibly versioning it as an artifact, and then deploying it to one or more SpagoBI servers in an automated fashion,  see my working SpagoBI Export deployer project in Github  [dbh / SpagoBIInteg](https://github.com/dbh/SpagoBIInteg) and my blog post [SpagoBI report deployment via SDK](https://www.davidbharrison.com/spagobi-doc-deploy-via-sdk/)

Here is a former discussion thread on the [Spago World forum](https://www.spagoworld.org/jforum/posts/list/3563.page) which which went without comment.

If you find any of this useful, please let me know. I'm happy to collaborate.